# Bordism Group $\eta_{4}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $\eta_{n}$ the $n$ bordism group of a single point, i have to show that $\eta_{4}=\mathbb{Z}_{2}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{2}$, i don't know how to see that $\eta_{4}$ has 2 generators.

Comment: I think you are thinking about the O (unorientable cases) bordism group - please clarify!!!